# need help debugging to output if the adjusted list is in order of ascension

Tags: python, arrays, debugging, append

The task question is:

> You are given an array of non-negative integers numbers. You are allowed to choose any number from this array and swap any two digits in it. If after the swap operation the number contains leading zeros, they can be omitted and not considered (eg: 010 will be considered just 10).
>
> Your task is to check whether it is possible to apply the swap operation at most once, so that the elements of the resulting array are strictly increasing.
> For numbers = [1, 5, 10, 20], the output should be solution(numbers) = true.

Here are some examples to show what they mean:

> The initial array is already strictly increasing, so no actions are required.
> For numbers = [1, 3, 900, 10], the output should be solution(numbers) = true.
>
> By choosing numbers[2] = 900 and swapping its first and third digits, the resulting number 009 is considered to be just 9. So the updated array will look like [1, 3, 9, 10], which is strictly increasing.
>
> For numbers = [13, 31, 30], the output should be solution(numbers) = false.
>
> The initial array elements are not increasing.
>
> By swapping the digits of numbers[0] = 13, the array becomes [31, 31, 30] which is not strictly increasing;
>
> By swapping the digits of numbers[1] = 31, the array becomes [13, 13, 30] which is not strictly increasing;
>
> By swapping the digits of numbers[2] = 30, the array becomes [13, 31, 3] which is not strictly increasing;
>
> So, it's not possible to obtain a strictly increasing array, and the answer is false.

I did this bit of code but there is something wrong with it.
When I do a test run, it is only appending the number that needs the swapping, not all the numbers.

I am just wondering if there's a way to fix the appending error or if there are more things wrong with my code.

```
def solution(numbers):
    if numbers == sorted(numbers):
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(numbers)-1):
            num_new = []
            num = 0
            if numbers[i] % 100 != 0:
                num_new.append(num) #issue around here, it's only appending the 900 as 9 not the rest
            else:
                num = numbers[i] / 100
                num_new.append(num)
        if num_new == sorted(numbers):
            return True
        else:
            return False

solution([1, 3, 900, 10])
```

Comment: What does "*there is something wrong with it*" mean? Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: @MattDMo in the code i added a note of the issue, it is only appending the 900 when i do the test run instead of appending all the elements of the entire list